# +[UIImage sd_imageWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, sdwebimage

SDWebImage has been running fine for me the past 6+ months, I just started using Cocoapods with SDWebImage, having previously statically linked the library into my iOS project.

After switching over to Cocoapods today, my app crashes with this erorr:

> +[UIImage sd_imageWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x25532cc

The only code update I made was to the SDWebImageDownloader | downloadImageWithURL so the project compiles (SDWebImage had a typedef update) to use NSInteger:

Previously:

```
downloadImageWithURL: url
             options: 0
            progress: ^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {  }
           completed: ^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
```

Updated to:

```
downloadImageWithURL: url
             options: 0
            progress: ^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {  }
           completed: ^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
```

Any ideas what could be causing it?  And how it could be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: are you opening up the workspace file or proj file?  If you are using CocoaPods you have to open the workspace file to compile your app.  Also make sure that you are #importing the SDWebImage header into your file, but I doubt that is the problem.  That would cause a compile error.

Comment: I'm opening the workspace file, and haven't had to change the original #import statement for SDWebImage. All other pods like TWStatus works fine...

Comment: @snowbound did you fix this problem? I have the same with iOS8

Comment: Hey @George, I couldn't fixed the issue back in Jun, so manually included the source for SDWebImage in my project.  Tested again recently with CocoaPods and it works fine across iOS7, iOS8 and all devices that I tested.  my line in PodFile reads: `pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.6'`  
I've had to change the call signature for `downloadImageWithURL` to NSInteger to make it work of course.  Let me know how you go!

Comment: Thank you for answer, @snowbound. I've updated lib with podfile, and now it works good! :)